# How do i check the number of time i clicked against List size?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
int count = 0;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> files = new DirectoryInfo(@"d:\")
    .GetFiles("*.avi")
    .Select(f => f.FullName + " " + FileSizeDisplay(f,70))//Select(f => Path.GetFileName(f.Name) + " " + FileSizeDisplay(f,70))
    .ToList();

    for (int i = files.Count -1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (!files[i].EndsWith("MB") || files[i].EndsWith("0 MB"))
        {
            files.RemoveAt(i);
        }
    }

    if (count < files.Count -1)
    {
        int index = files[count].IndexOf(" ");
        filetoupload = files[count].Substring(0, index);
        count += 1;
    }
}
```

In this line:

```
if (count < files.Count -1)
```

I have for example in files 13 items. Files is a `List<string>`.
If I will do only if `(count < files.Count)` it will throw exception when it's getting to 13.

If I'm doing `if (count < files.Count -1)` then it will show me that I clicked/uploaded 12 times/items.

Comment: What is the question? would you please ask the question more clear? How list size is related to number of clicks?

Comment: why don't you query the directory files e.g. size etc before doing the list instead of removing things from the list later...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this:

```
files.RemoveAt(i);
```

You have changed the number of items in the array. So next when you attempt to iterate over that array, you should expect it to possibly have less than the 13 items.